# use of jquery-latest

Tags: jquery

I recently had some code I wrote a year ago fail because someone linked my code to

> http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

In the latest version, jquery had deprecated/replaced a function.

Nice to have a dynamically updated version but my code isn't going to change, it's going to break. Is there any reason to use jquery-latest?

Comment: Are you asking in general if you should use the latest version of Jquery or for a specific reason for using the latest version of Jquery? There could be different answers depending.

Comment: I don't know how I can make it any clearer, the problem is linking to that specific file, jquery-latest which will always be the latest version, yet my code isn't so will eventually break. So why does it exist?

Comment: Because you will benefit from behind the scene updates, could be performance or bug-related.

Comment: @jimsmith Just because your code breaks doesn't mean everyone's will. Many people like getting the most recent updates to the jquery file (as max said there could be performance improvements and bugfixes). I'd imagine breaking changes with jquery are rare (such as a function being deprecated).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Latest" could be useful during initial development to keep up with the most recent changes.  jQuery does provide feature updates relatively often.  Expect your code using it to break.  **When you release your project you should support, reference, and document a specific jQuery version.**  Typically it's safe to reference a minor version and support revision changes since the interfaces won't change (e.g. 1.9.x).